# Render Twig template as XML

Tags: 8, emails

I want to send an XML mail using Drupal's `mailManager`.

I have created a custom twig template in my module that will the the mail body.

Here's what my template looks like, `my-module-xml-mail.html.twig`:

```
<record>
  <name>{{ name }}</name>
  <phone>{{ phone }}</phone>
  <email>{{ email }}</email>
</record>
```

And my template definition:

```
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'my_module_xml_mail' => [
      'variables' => [
        'name' => NULL,
        'phone' => NULL,
        'email' => NULL,
      ]
    ]
  ];
}
```

And where I send the mail:

```
$mail_message = [
  '#type' => 'theme',
  '#theme' => 'my_module_xml_mail',
  '#name' => 'Name',
  '#phone' => 'Phone',
  '#email' => 'E-mail',
];

$rendered = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($mail_message);

\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')->mail('my_module', 'xml_mail', 'test@example.com', 'en', [
  'message' => $rendered,
]);
```

The problem is that when the mail is sent all the XML tags are stripped and only the values from the tags are sent.

How can I send the XML as plain text?

I thought about creating a `my-module-xml-mail.xml.twig` if that's possible, but when `"kinting"` the result from the renderer service it looks like renderer is not stripping any tags.

Do I need to send any headers to the mail, in order to send the XML as plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

The problem is that Drupal's mail system converts HTML to plain text, and therefore strips all HTML tags.

A workaround to this is to replace all `<` and `>` characters with their unicode string and send the mail as `text/plain`.

I did like this:

```
$mail_message = [
  '#type' => 'theme',
  '#theme' => 'my_module_xml_mail',
  '#name' => 'Name',
  '#phone' => 'Phone',
  '#email' => 'E-mail',
];

$rendered = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($mail_message);

\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')->mail('my_module', 'xml_mail', 'test@example.com', 'en', [
  'message' => str_replace(['<', '>'], ['&#60;', '&#62;'], $rendered->__toString()),
]);
```

Comment: Why not sending an HTML mail in the first place?

Comment: That doesn't work either, `MailFormatHelper::htmlToText()` removes all the XML tags even though I'm sending it as an HTML mail.

Comment: Is it actually sending as text/html though?

Comment: @Kevin I don't understand your question. I send the mail as `text/plain`.

Comment: I just convert the `<` and `>` characters, so they dont get stripped when creating the mail.